# Strongly typed Viewbag items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewbag

If I am using a ViewBag which contains a strongly typed object, is there any way on MVC Razor to define (or cast this) so that all the elements of that appear in the IntelliSense?

For example lets say I have

```
ViewBag.Movies.Name
ViewBag.Movies.Length
```

I know Movies is of object type Movie, which has the members Name and length

```
class Movie { 
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Length {get; set;}
}
```

Can I somehow cast this, like I do for model

```
@model Transactions.UserTransactionDetails
```

So that the members of Movie become available in Razor?

Comment: ViewBag simply isn't strongly typed, so you should use a strongly typed model for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a ViewModel, which contains properties for all the different objects that you view needs

e.g.

```
public class MovieTransactionViewModel 
{
   public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
   public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

Then, have your view use this as it's model, and you will get intellisense in your view.

That way you are not changing your models, so EntityFramework will not be affected.

Answer (score 17):

You could store it in a variable.

```
var movie = (Movie)ViewBag.Movie;
```

Then typing `@movie.` will produce intellisense for `Name`, `Length`.

Answer (score 3):

Stay away from VieWbag:
http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/12/stop-using-viewbag-in-most-places.html

Simply create a new VieWModel that contains other models within it.

Comment: Sometimes it's useful. For example, when you want to set the title and meda-description properties in the `<head>` section of _Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

No. That is because ViewBag is not strongly typed. It is implemented using dynamics and ExpandoObject. If you need a strongly typed model, why don't you use one?

Comment: I'm already using a model to pass back and forth transaction information for a user form, so didn't think I could have 2 models :(

Comment: Can't you just add the data you need to your model? Are you using view models?

Comment: Its a good idea to use ViewModels (in general), but it is "required" if you are going to need to use entities from multiple models.

Comment: The Movie is actually held in a Entity Framework object. The other is held in a view model (user transaction). I'm doing validation using the user transaction model with validation flags set. When I was combining them both I couldn't get the validation to fire correct. Hence the putting one into viewbag :| Sorry still learning here :)